# audio file ds2 format to wav conversion in CentOS

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, wav, librosa

I am trying to convert ds2 format audio file to wav in a python / c++ based solution. Basically, I want to read ds2 audio in Linux with any codec. I tried ffmpeg and pydub, but failed. Is there any other library or solution which can handle this conversion on linux?

```
ffmpeg -i audio_input.DS2  -acodec dss_sp -ar 16000 -ac 2 output.wav
```

with ffmpeg I used the above command and it has thrown an error. Can anyone suggest which library would make it possible on CentOS? or any piece of command which can help to read ds2 which can be converted to any other conventional format.

Comment: Do you have an example file that we can test on?

Comment: It seems that DS2 is *not* supported in ffmpeg. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6091

Comment: I can provide you example with DSS/DS2

Comment: its not necessarily ffmpeg, any library or codec which I can install on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux with wine there is also [switch from nch.com.au](https://www.nch.com.au/switch/), free for personal use only.

The graphical interface works fine on my Fedora desktop and you can use [cli for automation](http://help.nchsoftware.com/help/en/switch/win/switchcommandlinetool.html)

Here a example with output in ~/Musics by default

```
/usr/bin/wine /home/mylogin/.wine/dosdevices/c\:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/NCH\ Software/Switch/switch.exe -convert "Z:\home\mylogin\transcriptions\interviews\myinterview.DS2" -format .wav -overwrite ALWAYS -hide
```

Answer (score 2):

As of early 2021, the Olympus DSS Pro Audio format (aka Digital Speech Standard Pro or DS2) are not supported by any software designed to run on Linux. There is an [open ticket for ffmpeg to support DS2](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6091).

There are only a few softwares for Windows that supports this format. These include:

- [Olympus DSS Player Lite](https://www.olympus-europa.com/site/en/a/audio_software/transcription_software/dss_player/dss_player_lite_s_2/index.html)
- [Olympus DSS Player Standard](https://dl-support.olympus-imaging.com/odms_download/dss_player_standard_r2/en/)
- [Bytescribe WavPlayer](https://www.bytescribe.com/)

These may be used to convert the audio into an open format, such as WAV. From there you can convert into your desired formats using ffmpeg or similar.

Some of these might run on Linux using the [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/) compatibility layer. There is at least positive reports for [DSS Player Lite](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5268).

Comment: Thank you, yes, these I have seen but they are not open source. Needs specific licenses. Maybe, there is any solution in C++ which can be used with python wrapper or directly C++ solution.

Comment: Could be, but I have not found any. If anyone does find an open implementation, or just hints on the file format structure, I hope they post it here